# Show actual currency to 2 decimal places in Visual Force Email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I have an visual force email tempalte however the currency field is giving me some problems:

We are writing to advise you that an amount of £{!relatedTo.Amount__c} is outstanding on your account

This works ok however if the amount is £200.00 when the email is sent it displays as £200.0

The same thing happens if this is £200.50 it will show as £200.5

It works correctly when the amount is e.g £200.11

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, 00.00}">
      <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Amount__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Have a nice day.

Comment: quick question - do you know how I would get the currency sign infront of figure for example £200.00

Comment: I think you can had '£' before '{0, number, 00.00}' in the value attribute of the ouputtext.

Comment: Hi Martin I have tried this but seems to be attaching it to the word before the currency amount like below: an amount of£ 136.25 is outstanding? any ideas?

Comment: Hi Josh ! I'm sorry I don't understand why it's not working. Maybe you can try this: <apex:outputText value="{0, number, £00.00}">

Comment: The doc for the pattern is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html. Note also the ##.00 versus 00.00 to suppress leading zeroes