# Invoice Notice amount in the subject of the Visualforce email template is not displaying the second decimal

Tags: visualforce, email-template

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!relatedTo.Invoice__r.Account__r.Name} -
                                Invoice notice - 
                                ${relatedTo.Invoice__r.Invoice_Balance__c} - 
                                Due {!relatedTo.Invoice__r.Due_Date__c}"
                        recipientType="Contact"
                        relatedToType="Invoice_Comment__c">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
```

I'm getting the following  (not getting the second decimal in the currency field)

Dell - Invoice notice - $28123.0 - Due 03/26/2016

Any suggestion to get the 2nd zero.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked that the field is defined to display 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

If you cant configure the field to display it, you can use merge fields to do it for you in the email. Theyll be parsed before the email is sent out, so the user will only see the resulting value. You can see this used [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100793/show-actual-curreny-to-2-decimal-places-in-visual-force-email-template?rq=1).